# Expand SVG path to fit container of all dimensions

Tags: svg

I'm trying to have a SVG path scale to fit the entire container element, without stretching or being trimmed. The SVG is the one below. As you can see, it's a simple border.

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 370 80" height="100%" width="100%">
    <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M359,70C359,70,300,70,185,70C84,70,9,70,9,70C9,70,9,60,9,40C9,24,9,10,9,10C9,10,84,10,185,10C300,10,359,10,359,10C359,10,359,24,359,40C359,60,359,70,359,70C359,70,359,70,359,70"/>
</svg>
```

Then I have an element that could have different sizes, because it's responsive and because I use it in various cases where width or height can be different. I can't succeed in having the SVG that expands its path by always staying inside the viewport, but scaling without preserving aspect ratio. It doesn't seem a difficult logical thing to do, but I tried various options without success.

**EDIT**

I was able to scale this SVG, by setting whatever dimensions I wanted. Why does the first not work, but this works instead?

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 404 77" height="100%" width="100%">
    <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="m0,0l404,0l0,77l-404,0l0,-77z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  What you want to do (as I understand it) is not possible.  In SVG you can scale to fit the container (using constant aspect ratio), or you can stretch (ignoring aspect ratio).

There is no way currently to keep some parts of the SVG static and stretch other parts.  Unless, of course, you use Javascript to manipulate the contents of the SVG.

What you may want to do is consider using an SVG as the source image for a CSS `border-image` (see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images).  Perhaps that is the sort of thing you were after?

Comment: Thank you, I changed the SVG to another one and I was able to scale it very well, I tried various dimensions and it worked. Could you explain me why the second SVG scales as I want and the first doesn't work?

Comment: Ah I see.  The reason is because the viewBox in your second SVG exactly matches the contents.  That is not true of the first one.  In your first one, the bounding box of the path is smaller than your viewBox.  If you set the viewBox to "9 10 350 60" (to match the bounding box of the path) it will behave the same as the second SVG.

Comment: In your quetion, you said you wanted it to fit "without stretching".  However in your second SVG stretching *is* happening, you just can't see it because the SVG is just a black rectangle.  If you had other things in there  like lines or circles, the stretching will become apparent.